# Есть-ли возможность настроить позицию колонки с номерами строк в UNIX утилите less?

Tags: linux, unix, shell, utility

Всем привет! Есть-ли возможность, в [стандартном](http://www.greenwoodsoftware.com/less) юниксовом `less`, при включённом параметре `-N` (показ номеров строк) сдвинуть колонку с номерами строк к левому краю? В мане я что-то такого не нашёл, но может невнимательно смотрел. *less v563, Manjaro Linux*
[image: Пруфпик]

Comment: `$ nl -n ln /etc/fstab | less`

Comment: Это не ответ на вопрос, но вариант, да. Спасибо!

Comment: Правда для приложений использующих пейджер (`man`, `systemctl`, etc) придётся накостылить враппер.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сам спросил, сам ответил. В следующем релизе будет опция `--line-num-width` В git [добавлена](https://github.com/gwsw/less/issues/103) 22 дня назад.